# How use data returned by jquery.ajax in ng-repeat?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here is my jquery ajax call

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url: view_url+"get_messagekinds",
            success: function (result) {
                $scope.response = result;
            },
            async: false
        });
```

and here is html code:

```
<select id="select_msg_kind"
                    name="select_msg_kind"
                    class="form-control"
                    ng-model="message_kind_selected" style="height:30px;width:220px">
                    <option value="0">--Select Message Kind--</option>
                    <option ng-repeat="res in response track by $index" value="{{ res.id }}">
                        {{ res.name }}
                    </option>
                </select>
```

but select list is empty. here is screenshot

[image]

How can i populate select list with data returned by ajax call using ng-repeat?

Here is data returned by ajax call:

```
[{"id": 1, "name": "Test1"}, {"id": 2, "name": "test2"}, {"id": 3, "name": "Test3"}]
```

Comment: please add the result from ajax as well

Comment: @guradio updated my question

Comment: Tip: Don't use `jQuery.ajax`, instead use angular's `$http`-service. The latter will notice angular that a so called "digest-cycle" should run

Comment: i needed synchronous call. can you give me synchronous code for angularjs as i have searched but not found any satisfactory solution

Comment: @ShoaibAkhtar You should never need nor use any synchronous AJAX calls in JavaScript [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call#answer-14220323) may help you find a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Tip: Don't use `jQuery.ajax`, instead use angular's `$http`-service. The latter will notice angular that a so called "digest-cycle" should run:

```
$http.get(url).then(function(result) {
    // success
    $scope.response = result;
}, function() {
    // error
});
```

If you really want to use jquery's ajax (I think your reason is because you use `async: false`), you should trigger the digest cycle yourself:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: view_url+"get_messagekinds",
    success: function (result) {
        // trigger digest cycle with '$apply'
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.response = result;
        });
    },
    async: false
});
```

You should not use async however, you can just use the promises and the callback functions of the `$http` service.

Comment: getting this error:

angular.min.js:107 Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.4/$rootScope/inprog?p0=NaNigest
    at Error (native)
    at http://10.10.10.10:8000/static/cmt_beta/js/angular.min.js:6:416
    at q (http://10.10.10.10:8000/static/cmt_beta/js/angular.min.js:125:271)
    at n.$apply